# Swap words but preserve other characters between two strings

Tags: python, string, nlp

Say I took a sentence and swapped out some words. I started with an input sentence:

`sentence = Wow, it felt so nice outside today!`

Then I tokenized it and swapped out some words. I'm left with a list of the new words, like:

`['Hey', 'I', 'felt', 'somewhat', 'dreary', 'inside', 'today']`

I want to convert this list of words back to the original format, preserving whitespace and special characters, and end up with a string like:

`Hey, I felt somewhat dreary inside today!`

The first sentence can have any type of whitespace or special characters in between the words. Is there an easy way to do this algorithmically, hopefully without iterating through the original string character by character? I'm using Python.

*Note that the reconstructed sentence has to retain the intermediate whitespace and punctuation, so I cannot just use the join() function.*

Comment: If x=['a','b'] then ''.join(x) returns 'ab'

Comment: Not 100% I know what you are going for. Is the input an actual "input()"? If so that makes my next steps a bit harder. If you have preset sentences and simple want to swap out a word or two.  You can have an array and then use random to pick one. You can then place the sentence with the swapped out with inside an f string.      f"Wow, it felt so {my_str} outside today!."

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
sentence = "Wow, it felt so nice outside today!"
new_word=re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?; ]",sentence)
```

Do your replacement at the order.

```
 new_words=['Hey', ',', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'felt', ' ', 'somewhat', ' ', 'dreary', ' ', 'inside', ' ', 'today', '!']
```

If you have sorted this order then after this you can use it.

```
 print("".join(new_words))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem: using `replace`.

```
for input_word, new_word in zip(input_words, new_words):
   raw_sentence = raw_sentence.replace(input_word, new_word, 1)
return raw_sentence
```

By adding the parameter `1`, you specify to only replace `input_word` the first time that it occurs in `raw_sentence`.

Probably not the most efficient way since I'm calling `replace` N times. This is worst-case O(N^2), and there is a more complicated way to do this in O(N). But I'm not doing it too often, and this code is quite readable. So it works for me!